# How to grep for case insensitive string in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a file `file1` which ends with
`Success...` OR
`success...`

I want to `grep` for the word `success` in a way which is not case sensitive way.

I have written the following command but it is case sensitive

```
cat file1 | grep "success\.\.\."
```

How can i change it so that it `returns 0` with both `Success...` OR
`success...`

Answer (score 410, accepted):

You can use the `-i` flag which makes your pattern case insensitive:

```
grep -iF "success..." file1
```

Also, there is no need for `cat`. `grep` takes a file with the syntax `grep <pattern> <file>`. I also used the `-F` flag to search for a fixed string to avoid escaping the ellipsis.

Comment: doesn't simple `grep -i success file1` returns the same output as expected here?

Comment: @User123 Yes, but `-F` searches for the exact string, without doing any regex parsing, so it's often faster and easier to type if you (as the OP did) have special characters in the phrase you're looking for

Comment: why did you use `F`?

Comment: @ashish_k `grep -i success file1` will find a match in a file that contains (for example) "not successful" but does not contain "success..."

Answer (score 3):

Since this bubbled up due to an edit being made, I'll add another method just for the fun of it.

```
grep '[Ss]uccess' file.txt
```

This uses the regular expression syntax for a character class of capital or lower 's'.

Answer (score 2):

For me SQL=`echo $line | grep -iF "SQL"`;
IT works perfect

Comment: could you explain what this is doing?