# How to remove specific phrase from csv file

Tags: bash

So I've got a CSV file, `test.csv`, with the following:

```
Apples
Pears
Oranges
```

They would be comma separated given its a csv file.

I have a variables

```
test="app"
```

I want to remove anything from the csv file with that variable contents in it. So the output would be in a new file test1.csv:

```
Pears
Oranges
```

Comment: Does `apPles` would also be removed?

Comment: http://geekbraindump.blogspot.com/2010/06/case-insensitive-regex-in-bash.html

Comment: `grep -vi "app" test.csv`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to invert a grep expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373675/how-to-invert-a-grep-expression) in combination with [How to grep for case insensitive string in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492422/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use `sed` to do that.**

If you want to remove the **entire row** that contains `test` variable's value. Then try-

```
user@localhost$ sed "/$test/d" test.csv > output.csv
```

If you want to replace the **word** that holds the var `test`, then try -

```
user@localhost$ replacewith=''
user@localhost$ sed "s/$test/$replacewith/g" test.csv > output.csv
```

**NB: Replace and Delete can mean same thing if you use blank string as replacement.**

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain such a result with sed:

```
sed '/dog/d' inputfile.csv > outputfile.csv
```

You can also make it case insensitive:

```
sed '/[dD][oO][gG]/d' inputfile.csv > outputfile.csv
```

The syntax used in the latter is RegEx, read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).